# Aggregate queryset to calculate percentage is always returning 0

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a Django queryset that aggregates the percentage of verified contracts in our system. I can't seem to get it to work though - I'm always getting '0' for the percentage, even though I know that it should be closer to 25%.

My current attempts follows:

```
In[1]: Contract.objects.aggregate(
    total=Count('pk'),
    verified=Count('pk', filter=Q(verified_date__isnull=False)
)
Out[1]: {'total': 4000, 'verified': 1000}

In[2]: Contract.objects.aggregate(
    percentage=Count('pk', filter=Q(verified_date__isnull=False)) / Count('pk')
)
Out[2]: {'percentage': 0}

In[3]: Contract.objects.aggregate(
    percentage=Count('pk', filter=Q(verified_date__isnull=False), output_field=DecimalField()) / Count('pk', output_field=DecimalField())
)
Out[3]: {'percentage': Decimal('0')}
```

Comment: Your app thinks that the **percentage** column is an integer, and not a decimal.  When you calculate `Count('pk', filter=Q(verified_date__isnull=False)) / Count('pk')`, you end up with **0.25**, which is rounded to 0, since **percentage** is an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the values decimal before dividing them, just multiply by 1.0 to make sure of that:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, Count, Value, DecimalField

Contract.objects.aggregate(perc=ExpressionWrapper(
    Count('pk', filter=Q(verified_date__isnull=False)) * Value(1.0) 
    / (Count('pk') * Value(1.0)), 
    output_field=DecimalField()))
```

I use `ExpressionWrapper` to be able to set the `output_field` parameter on the aggregation value itself.

**UPDATE:**
After looking at [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26650) based on the comment that *casting* with `output_field` should have worked, I've found that this works as well:

```
from django.db.models import Count, DecimalField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Contract.objects.aggregate(perc=
    Cast(
        Count('pk', filter=Q(verified_date__isnull=False)), 
        DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=4)
    ) 
    / Cast(
        Count('pk'), 
        DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=4)
    )
)
```

The issue mentioned above explains why `output_field` doesn't work. Seems to be a tbd for the future :-)

Comment: I don't think you need to multiply by `Value(1.0)` (I could be wrong).

Comment: Ah, interesting. Looks like I misunderstood how the `output_field` paramter worked. I figured that'd do the cast for me. Looks like I only need the `Value(1.0)` on the second count too. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I would have expect the cast to work as well. Maybe this should be reported as an issue.